# I want to read Gmail messages in Android

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api

I want to get user email messages or tokens from Gmail in an Android application. How can I get a user's messages and token from Gmail? I need an example application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the example from here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

Later, instead request the labels you need to ask for messages so you need to update function 'getDataFromApi' to get messages :

```
 private static final long MAX_RESULTS_PER_REQUEST = 20;
private void getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
List<String> labelsId = new ArrayList<>();
labelsId.add("INBOX");
ListMessagesResponse response=null;
response = mService.users().messages().list("me").setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS_PER_REQUEST).setLabelIds(labelsId).execute();
List<Message> messages = response.getMessages();
for (Message message : messages) {
     Message curMessage = mService.users().messages().get("me", message.getId()).execute();
     System.out.println("cur message==>"+curMessage);    
   }
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example plese. I can't understand google documentation. I need an example please.

Comment: @MetinTaşdeğer But this is full example there how to get information from gmail api in android... what example you want?

Comment: can you share an example for getDataFromApi to get messages please.  I dont make this example

Comment: @MetinTaşdeğer I update my answer , this is my function . What I do here is to get the first 20 messages in the inbox and print it to see message details..

Comment: I am thankfull for you your code is runnig thank you :)

Comment: Anyway to fetch all label's name in gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this using [Content Provider API of Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/)

> The Android Gmail app starting in versions 2.3.6 (Froyo/Gingerbread)
>   and 4.0.5 (Honeycomb/ICS) includes a new Content Provider API that
>   third party developers can use to retrieve label information like name
>   and unread count, and stay updated as that information changes

To see an example of this API in action, check out [the sample app](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/android-gmail-api-sample.tar.gz).

Comment: This content provider api only gives the labels of the selected account. You cannot read any messages with that.